# Calculation of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Because I did not get the answer I wanted in my previous questions, I will ask there more properly.

I have this differential equation $$xy'+y=y^2$$
I make it look like $$xy'=y^2-y$$
Then divide it by $x*(y^2-y)$ (must notice that $x\neq0$ and $y\neq0$ and $y\neq1$) $$\frac{y'}{y^2-y} = \frac{1}{x}$$

- And this is important question #1: I see that there are two stacionar solutions, namely $y=0$ and $y=1$, do I have to include condition $x\neq0$ in their domain? I ask, because I calculate the differential equation based on the assignment and there $x=0$ is legal. So with this in mind, is the domain of these stacionar solutions $R$ or $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$?

We continue with calculation and get this $$y=\frac{1}{1-xc}$$

Now I want to make general domain:

- Question #2 which coexist with #1 Do I have to include condition  $x\neq0$ even if there is $x=0$ legal in assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on if you approach the solution of differential equations as a general theory for "black box" right sides or as a motley collection of tricks that can be used to solve a selective class of tutorial examples of differential equations. I'm going to address the first, generalist approach.

---

The *first* step is to look at the normalized, that is, explicit form of the DE
$$
y'=f(x,y)=\frac{y^2-y}x
$$
This shows that the DE is *undefined* at $x=0$, so that the domain of the DE, as a connected open set, is either $(-\infty,0)\times\Bbb R$ or $(0,+\infty)\times\Bbb R$. This restricts the domain of any solution to be a subset of either $(-\infty,0)$ or $(0,+\infty)$.

*Secondly*, the exclusion of $y=0$ or $y=1$ or both is completely an *artifact* of the solution method used, it is not a restriction to the domain of the DE. So both constant functions are solutions, within the mentioned restriction of their domain as solutions of the DE. To find other solutions one may exclude these values from consideration by the uniqueness part of the existence theorem.

*Thirdly*, besides the static restrictions on the domain, a solution can also have a decreased domain due to *dynamical blow-up*, as is the case here due to the quadratic term providing positive super-linear feed-back. Remember that a solution is a continuously differentiable function, if the expression you find contains poles or other singularities, the solution has to be restricted to an interval that does not contain these points. Here the pole position is $x=\frac1c$, where $c$ is a function of the initial condition $(x_0,y_0)$. The domain of the solution is obviously that sub-interval that contains $x_0$.

Comment: Ok, so domain for solution $y=0$ is $(-\infty,0)$ or $(0,\infty)$. Domain for solution $y=1$ is $(-\infty,0)$ or $(0,\infty)$. Domain for $y=\frac{1}{1-xc}$ is for c<0 $(-\infty,\frac{1}{c})$ or ($\frac{1}{c},0)$ or $(0,\infty)$ and for c>0 $(-\infty,0)$ or $(0,\frac{1}{c}$) or $(\frac{1}{c},\infty)$ ?

Comment: Why the downvote ? This answer is a great and valuable answer. +1

Comment: is my comment right or not?

Comment: Yes, the comment is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with $x=0$. There are indeed two constant solutions, $y(x)=0$ and $y(x)=1$, valid for all $x$.

Now we solve with $z:=xy$, indeed giving

$$z'=y^2$$ or $$\frac{z'}{z^2}=\frac1{x^2}$$ giving

$$\frac1z=\frac1x+c,$$
$$y=\frac1{1+cx}.$$

This solution is valid for all $x\ne-\dfrac1c$ and $-\dfrac1c\ne0$. In fact, $x=0$ is the only value which cannot be problematic.

Comment: Now I am a little bit confused, because there are two different views.

Comment: @naruto25: $x=0\implies y=y^2$ so that $y=0$ or $y=1$. There is no reason to exclude $x=0$. The "normalized form" as described in another answer introduces a singularity artificially.

Comment: So even when I am solving this equation as with separable variables I can include $x=0$ then? My answer then is: there are two stacionar solutions $y=0$ and $y=1$, bot have domain $x\in R$. Then there is this general solution $y=\frac{1}{1+cx}$. Domain for this, when $c\neq0$ is $(-\infty,\frac{1}{c})$ or $(\frac{1}{c},\infty)$. But we can merge $y=1$ and $y=\frac{1}{1+cx}$ together for $c=0$, right? So for $c=0$ the domain will be $x\in R$

Comment: is it right, or not?

Comment: In the sense of the existence and uniqueness theorems, the line $x=0$ has to be excluded. Of course, as the solutions have limits towards $x=0$, one can combine solutions from the left and right to get a continuous function, $y(x)=\frac1{1+c_1x}$ for $x<0$, $y(0)=1$ and $y(x)=\frac1{1+c_2x}$. There is nothing in the equation that forces differentiability in $x=0$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann: stop the harassement.